# Linking to detail pages in Rally custom apps

Tags: javascript, sdk, rally

I have been using the following code to insert a hyperlinked FormattedID into my grid. I can't use the standard formatting template because my grid has both User Stories and Features. When I click one of the links it takes me to a blank page (with the Rally wrapper). If I copy and paste the URL into the nav bar everything works perfect so I know the link isn't bad. The error the page is throwing is "TypeError: mainWindow.Rally.alm is undefined".

```
var idLink = i.get('FormattedID');
if (idLink.match('US')) idLink = '<a href="https://rally1.rallydev.com/#/detail/userstory/' + i.get('ObjectID') + '" target="_blank">' + idLink + '</a>';
else if (idLink.match('F')) idLink = '<a href ="https://rally1.rallydev.com/#/detail/portfolioitem/feature/' + i.get('ObjectID') + '" target="_blank">' + idLink + '</a>';
```

Also, if I take out the "target='_blank'" option the details page loads fine. But I would rather leave it in since my apps run within an iframe. It looks a little silly having a Rally page (wrapper and all) load within another Rally page. Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We currently know this is a pretty big hole in our public API.  The unreleased head revision of the SDK has better support for rending links in apps (Rally.util.DetailLink).

Look for it in the next preview version of the SDK and/or the GA.

Comment: Can we use this now, even though it is private?  I tried using this to create detail links, and it gives me the error: "Cannot call method `getLink` of undefined"

Comment: Or, rather, I guess a better question is:  Is there better support for opening detail links from within apps?

Comment: In 2.0rc1 you can do the following: Rally.nav.DetailLink.getLink({record: {_ref: '/hierarchicalrequirement/1', FormattedID: 'US1'}});  Note that record may be a model instance or a raw object.  It's marked as private since  we're not totally done with it yet.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately this isn't a supported use case detail pages, although I can certainly see how this would be a useful page rendering option.

I'd recommend posting this as an Idea out on [Rally Ideas](http://ideas.rallydev.com), so that other Rally customers can vote on it and gain visibility and traction as a feature request in the product.